# Anonymous editing of Jekyll page in Prose editor

Tags: github, jekyll, prose

I want to let anonymous visitors of my site based on Jekyll-Github-Pages do some edits without logging in. [image: Screen of sample page and link]

Here is [sample page](http://indexmod.club/abolenkin-andrei) which is must easy switched to Prose.io interface with the following link:

`[Edit](http://prose.io/#indexmod/{{site.repo}}/edit/{{site.branch}}/{{page.path}})`

This link just redirects to the page of Prose.io with the list of all my Github projects instead of page.path.

[image: Screen of Prose interface]

The question is how to modify this link to point editor to same page and let the editor do changes and push them without any authorization?